# How to expand rows limit in Tera Data studio?

Tags: teradata

I have a sql command like this below

```
SELECT * FROM READ_NOS_FM (
ON (SELECT cast (NULL as JSON))
USING
LOCATION('/s3/bigXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/JSONDATA/09380000/')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_RECORD')
) AS D;
```

result:  return over 2000 rows , be blocked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/biIkK.jpg

Comment: Click "No" or increase the "Max Rows" (as seen on your screenshot) or change it in the preferences.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OvRn3xt     you are right . copy your answer  to the answer filed  below, I will  chose your answer as the  correct answer.